# PERL Net::DNS output to file

Tags: perl, dns

Completely new to Perl (in the process of learning) and need some help.  Here is some code that I found which prints results to the screen great, but I want it printed to a file.  How can I do this?  When I open a file and send output to it, I get garbage data.

Here is the code:

```
use Net::DNS;
my $res  = Net::DNS::Resolver->new;
$res->nameservers("ns.example.com");

my @zone = $res->axfr("example.com");

foreach $rr (@zone) {
$rr->print;
}
```

When I add:

```
open(my $fh, '>', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
.....
$rr -> $fh; #I get garbage.
```

Comment: saying you've got "garbage" isn't particularly helpful without at least a small example of what that garbage looks like

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `@zone` array contains a list of [`Net::DNS::RR`](http://metacpan.org/module/Net::DNS::RR) objects, whose `print` method stringifies the object and prints it to the currently selected file handle

To print the same thing to a different file handle you will have to stringify the object yourself

This should work

```
open my $fh, '>', $filename or die "Could not open file '$filename': $!";

print $fh $_->string, "\n" for @zone;
```

Comment: Thanks....this output to the file was the same as the output was to the screen.  Much to learn on Perl.

Answer (score 3):

When you're learning a new language, making random changes to code in the hope that they will do what you want is not a good idea. A far better approach is to read the documentation for the libraries and functions that you are using.

The original code uses `$rr->print`. The documentation for [Net::DNS::Resolver](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::DNS::Resolver#print) says:

> **print**
>
> ```
> $resolver->print;
> ```
>
> Prints the resolver state on the standard output.

The `print()` method there is named after the standard Perl [`print`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html) function which we can use to print data to any filehandle. There's a Net::DNS::Resolver method called [`string`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html) which is documented like this:

> **string**
>
> ```
> print $resolver->string;
> ```
>
> Returns a string representation of the resolver state.

So it looks like `$rr->print` is equivalent to `print $rr->string`. And it's simple enough to change that to print to your new filehandle.

```
print $fh $rr->string;
```

p.s. And, by the way, it's "Perl", not "PERL".

Comment: The `print` method is exactly `print shift->string, "\n"`, so rather than printing to `STDOUT` as the documentation says, it actually prints to the currently selected file handle